# Trouble using preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

How can I use `preg_match_all` function to retrieve all colors from the following example:

```
Name: jonathan
Color: blue
Gender: male
=========================
Name: anthony
Color: yellow
Gender: male
=========================
Name: sandra
Color: pink
Gender: female
=========================
Name: marry
Color: white
Gender: female
=========================
Name: david
Color: black
Gender: male
=========================
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: is this array or file with content

Comment: put more info...\

Comment: @Learner nothing yet as I can't quite understand examples from php.net.

Comment: go try something or watch youtube videos and if you cant get it with your code, come and ask it\

Comment: @Learner this is file with content

Comment: So you have a file with HTML in it? You could format the question, so that it looks like file content. And you could write: "I have a file with this content:".

Comment: @KIKO Software I have a file with simple text. not HTML

Comment: @KIKO Software I'm a newbie. Sorry for that. I didn't knew.

Comment: I can see you're new to Stack Overflow. No problem with that, we all had to learn this. You can still edit your question. Nevertheless, it is normal to first do some research yourself, try something, and show that here. Tell us what you don't get about how `preg_match_all()` works. You could also read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which is linked on the page you typed in your question.

Comment: @KIKO Software Thanks for the tip man. I have used preg_match_all in other circumstances but I can't seem to find a good example how you can use the function to retrieve a word between a string and a new line. In my case between "Color: " and new line.

Comment: So this is about how to write regular expressions? I always find it useful to use this site: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Knka37/1) (after learning how reg exp works). Play with it! Note that this site doesn't do 'all', it just does it once. Note how you get answers that just give you a solution, but don't explain anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way to capture the color followed by the word `Color:`

```
<?php

$re = '/Color: (.*)/m';
$str = 'Name: jonathan
Color: blue

Gender: male
Name: anthony
Color: yellow

Gender: male
Name: sandra
Color: pink

Gender: female
Name: marry
Color: white

Gender: female
Name: david
Color: black

Gender: male';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
// Print the entire match result
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo $match[1].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough on what data type are you dealing with (String, Object, array, etc) but if you are dealing with a string try

```php
preg_match_all ('/(C|c)olor:\w*?\s.*/m', $yourString, $resultArray)
```

[preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) from php return an array of all matches in by the expression in the string, in this case it will be all the colors in the string.

Full example can be

```php
<?php

$myString = 
'Name: jonathan
Color: blue

Gender: male
Name: anthony
Color: yellow

Gender: male
Name: sandra
Color: pink';

preg_match_all('/(C|c)olor:\w*?\s.*/m', $myString, $resultArray);

<pre>
printr($resultArray)
</pre>

?>
```